# Cannot use Success and Failure block with UIImageView+AFNetworking.h

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to add a Success and Error block to check when the image is loaded so that I can use NSCache to dynamically resize the image. But when I try

```
[scribbleImage setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:scribble[@"scribble_image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"] success:^(UIImage *image) {
NSLog(@"done");
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"error %@",error);
}];
```

Xcode gives me an error, saying `No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:success:failure:'`

I am not sure why.

PS. I am importing UIImageView+AFNetworking.h and things work just fine without a success and failure block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the there is no method `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:success:failure:` there is just `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:scribble[@"scribble_image"]]];

[scribbleImage setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    NSLog(@"Done");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", error);
}];
```

If you look at what `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` does :

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
       placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [self setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:nil failure:nil];
}
```

You see that this is the method is used to fetch the internally as well.

Comment: rckoenes, what is imageRequest? did you mean to say request?

Comment: it gives me an error saying incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^((UIIImage*__strong)'....

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong part of my code, I've updated my answer with the correct method.

Comment: rckoenes, but with this the image does not load itself once its downloaded. it loads itself when I scroll down and back up

Comment: Weird because all `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` does is:`- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
       placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [self setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:nil failure:nil];
}`

Comment: I know! but is there a way I can fix this? or have you encountered this problem?

Comment: No I've never encountered that problem, how and where do you call the `setImageWithURLRequest:` method?

Comment: inside - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath as I have to add these images to individual cells

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26141/discussion-between-rckoenes-and-jonathan)